# devise でアクセス制限をかける方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
rails new mysite -d mysql
cd mysite
rails g scaffold memo
db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx を編集して
  t.string 'memo' 
追加
rake db:migrate
で localhost:3000/memo で index 画面確認

Gemfile に gem 'device' 追加
bundle install
rails g devise:install
rails g devise user
rake db:migrate
```

までやって `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` にアクセスすると
ログイン画面が表示されてうまくいったかと思ったんですけど
`localhost:3000/memo/` にアクセスすると一覧が表示されてしまいます

devise は単にユーザモデルとログイン画面を作るだけのジェムで
アクセス制限とかは自前で .htaccess とかをかく必要があるということですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ログインしなければ見せたくないコントローラー
例えば app/controller/memos_controler に

`before_action :authenticate_user!`

とかけばログインしてない場合コントローラー内に制御がくる前に
401 エラーになりログイン画面にリダイレクトされます

before_action はコントローラーのメソッドを実行する前に呼ばれる Rails のメソッドで
それをオーバーライドして devise の authenticate_user メソッドを呼ぶことで
ログインしてない場合に４０１を返すことができ、
それを受けて devise がログインフォームにリダイレクトします
（この辺も単に401ページを表示するだけとか設定 config/initializer/debvise.rb で変えられます）

あとログインユーザによって管理者、一般ユーザ等権限を分けて見られるページを細かく制御したい場合は
cancancan というジェムを併用するといいと思います

---

ちなみに質問タイトル device ではなく devise です

Comment: 制限できました！